# ie11 search input type clear icon refresh jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, datatables

This appears to be an ie only issue.  on ie11. when using input type = search a little x clear icon is shown. unfortunately clicking the clear button is not effecting my filter function on a jquery datatable.   here is an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/brzyvdps/5/

if you run the fiddle in ie11 and use the search fields on top of the table and then after they are populated click the little x clear icon the table is not changed to reflect there is not a filter for that field.

below is the filter function I am using. looks like the little x icon is not firing the change event ( I attempted adding mouseup as well but still nothing)

```
oTable.columns().every(function () {
                   var that = this;

                   $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                       if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                           that
                               .search(this.value)
                               .draw();
                       }
                   });
               });
```

Comment: yep adding input to the list of events fixed it. want to add that as answer or do you want to close this as a duplicate of the other question?

Comment: I guess a double answer is not needed, and this time, it looks like mr. Community was fast.

Comment: they usually are,  you gotta love stack overflow! always helpful